# Reinstalling MetaMask extention removes all other networks!

Tags: metamask

I was trying to clear all the failed/pending transactions on Ganache in my MetaMask account.

I previously used to have all networks (Rinkeby, etc.) now I only have the main net. Why is that?
[image]

How can I fix it? Do I need to add my local ganache mannually? I am somehow new to this, is there any advice to do so?

Many thanks!

Comment: The testnets are now hidden by default (Rinkeby, Ropsten etc.). You can enable them in the settings. You can also add new or restore old networks in the Networks tab as answered by @rsc05.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer is simple. One can simply go to the settings and add the networks as so
[image]

If that did now work, then go to Advance
[image]

scroll down to "Show test networks"

[image]